# What events trigger an answer to become community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

What are the events that will cause an answer to become community wiki?

(I'm sure this is a FAQ, but searching didn't locate the answer.)

Comment: This will answer your question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/205030

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no longer *any* automated triggers that will turn an answer into a community wiki. The only methods that an answer will become a community wiki are now:

- The person who posts the answer checks the community wiki box.
- A moderator manually converts it to community wiki for whatever reason.
- The answer is posted on a question which is already community wiki.

See the blog [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).